# Is this a Caesar silver coin?

Tags: ancient-rome, currency, numismatics

A friend showed me a coin he found a number of years a go,  but it is hard to identify if it is a Roman coin.

Can someone help me identify when it is from?

(images no longer available online at original URL, domain inactive July 2018)
https://s16.postimg.org/6pkjd7stx/IMG_20151211_164218.jpg
https://s2.postimg.org/u7n7qx0t5/IMG_20151211_163852.jpg

Comment: I will add the image shortly

Answer (score 9):

It is a Caesar denarius minted in 49 BC. This was the first type of coin Caesar had minted. The obverse is an elephant trampling a snake with CAESAR beneath. The reverse features the fetishes of the Pontifex Maximus, a title Caesar held at the time. See Roman Republican Coinage by Michael Crawford.

[image: obverse and reverse of coin]
<sup>Licence: Creative Commons Share Alike Attribution 2.5 -  Classical Numismatic Group, Inc.</sup>

Comment: Here is a clear image of such a coin: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CaesarElephant.jpg

Comment: Two years now and the OP has not still not accepted an answer (fairly active on several S.E sites, but has not been seen in 3 months). Cone on, OP, you know how S.E works - someone tried to help you. If the answer was good, accept it, to help others in future.